# How to specify color of CCLabelTTF having enableShadowWithOffset

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How do one use colors with [enableShadowWithOffset](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html#a6edfe9bfdde84e8e1897e8736fba4c38)?

As soon as I use it, it seems that the label color itself is changed to black as well as the shadow itself which is also black. Setting the font to any color seems to have no effect.

Setting color something like this

```
myttflabel.color = ccc3(255, 0, 0);
```

It would be nice to specify colors of:

- the text itself
- the shadow

For the sake of, here is how I currently use the shadow with cclabelttf:

```
CCLabelTTF* labelSlotid = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", menuitem.tag] fontName:@"GillSans-Bold" fontSize:11];
                [labelSlotid enableShadowWithOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1) opacity:1 blur:1 updateImage:YES];
                labelSlotid.color = ccc3(255, 0, 0);
                [menuitem addChild:labelSlotid];
```

Not sure but without setting updateImage to YES, no shadow is actually drawn.

Edit: I found [setFontFillColor](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.1.0/interface_c_c_label_t_t_f.html#a66dbf453adeff08121c747d2b8aca87e). It seems to work wonders. (Why didn't I see it before)

Answer (score 0):

The anser is `setFontFillColor`. However, there seems to be no direct way of setting shadow color.